# Батник или вбс-скрипт работающий с неопределенным кол-вом файлов

Tags: vbscript, bat

Доброго

Можно ли баткиком все файлы с расширением 'jpg' положить в рядом лежащую папку 'image' ? Ну и если можно, может кто кодом напугать?

p.s. на том же C#/Java вполне представляю как это сделать, даже на простятском PHP - без проблем. С обычным виндовым батником так и не смог разобраться

Comment: @mixalef, вот [тут есть алгоритм](http://hashcode.ru/questions/276740/cmd-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-bat-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0)  [тут, примерный код](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cmd-bat/thread640622.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легко на `PowerShell` такое сделать

```
$files = get-childitem <путь к файлам> -include *.jpg <регулярные выражения поддерживаются> -recurse <если хотите искать файлы в подпапках тоже>

foreach ($file in $files) {
    Copy-Item $file.FullName <путь назначения>
}
```